# Why does this grid not work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sass, grid

Works fine in chrome and firefox, but in IExplorer this grid seems to break.

Why does the last element of a row gets pushed down to next row as if it had no space?

I found out if I add  `margin-right: -0.3px` (line 17 on codepen) it fixes the problem in IE.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

codepen: https://codepen.io/Jaunbruns/pen/qxNENG

HTML:

```
 <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-of-1"> 1 / 1 </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2-of-3"> 2 / 3 </div>
            <div class="col-1-of-3"> 1 / 3 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3-of-4"> 3 / 4 </div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4 </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2-of-4"> 2 / 4 </div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-4"> 1 / 4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-12"> 1 / 12</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
            <div class="col-1-of-24"> 1 / 24</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  // default font-size = 16px
  // 10px = 62.5% of 16px

  font-size: 62.5%; // 1rem = 10px
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


@mixin clearfix {
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

$grid-width:  50rem;
$gutter-vertical: 2rem;
$gutter-horizontal: 0.5rem;

.row {
  max-width: $grid-width;
  background: rgba(209, 138, 138, 0.446);
  margin: 0 auto; // top-bot = 0 left right auto

  // put margin on all children except the last child
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;
  }
  @include clearfix;

  [class^="col-"] {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: limegreen;
    float: left;
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
    }

    &:last-child {
      background: #1a9b6e;
      margin-right: -0.3px;
    }
  }
}

@function calc-x-of-y($x,$y) {
  @return calc( (100% - ( #{$gutter-horizontal} * (#{$y} / #{$x} - 1)     ) ) /   (#{$y} / #{$x}) );
}

.col-1-of-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1-of-2 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(1, 2);
}

.col-1-of-3 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(1, 3);
}

.col-2-of-3 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(2, 3);
}

.col-2-of-4 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(2, 4);
}

.col-1-of-12 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(1, 12);
}

.col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(1, 4);
}

.col-1-of-24 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(1, 24);
}

.col-3-of-4 {
  width: calc-x-of-y(3, 4);
}
```

Comment: The reason is simple: IE.

Comment: Btw try using `*{ box-sizing: border-box; }` to your HTML. This helps with border and padding issues.

Comment: thanks, I added them.

Comment: Maybe you have set IE to use a different default font size.